# StructureMap non-generic configuration

Tags: .net, generics, structuremap

I am struggling with setting up StructureMap without the use of the
generic fluent interface,

I can't use the generic methods, because I don't know the types at
design time.

Ie:

To choose a default constructor the only method I could find is using
'SelectConstructor<T>()', but I only know the type at runtime...

This is related: http://groups.google.com/group/structuremap-users/browse_thread/threa...

How can I setup StructureMap without the generic fluent interfaces? Or, at least, how do I choose the default constructor without knowing the Type at design time.

Thanks in advance,

Remco

Answer (score 0):

Remco,

Can you post some code so we can have a better idea of the generic construction your trying to perform at runtime?

I was just [having issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116607/) with `SelectContructor<T>()` so maybe I could provide some insight or point you in the right direction.

njapp

Comment: Hmm. Can't remember the specific use-case anymore. 

It had something to do with the registration interface. Which has a lot of generic methods. But is missing the non-generic/(typeof) equivalents.

I investigated it all the way into the source of structuremap, but gave up as the underlying api's use generics everywhere.

We went with Castle Windsor in the end.