# Define default constructor with StructureMap without providing arguements or using DefaultConstructor attribute

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, structuremap

I've been using StructureMap for sometime now but I'm far from an expert.  My problem is simple, I'm trying to configure SM via code (Registry) to use a particular constructor when creating an instance of a repository object.

Here are my 2 constructors (note neither is the greediest).

```
public BusinessUnitRepository( IDatabase database )
    : base( database ) {

}

public BusinessUnitRepository( IDatabaseFactory factory )
    : base( factory ) {

}
```

Note: The first constructor takes an instance of the `IDatabase` interface and is called by the base class's ctor(IDatabaseFactory) implementation.

What I'm trying to do is configure SM to use the second constructor and provide an instance of `DatabaseFactory` from the SM container.  I can't use the `[DefaultConstructor]` attribute in the assembly where `BusinessUnitRepository` is defined so this option is off the table.

My Registry code

```
ForRequestedType<IDatabaseFactory>()
    .CacheBy( InstanceScope.PerRequest )
    .TheDefaultIsConcreteType<DatabaseFactory>();


ForRequestedType<Repository.IBusinessUnitRepository>()
    .CacheBy( InstanceScope.PerRequest )
    .TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType<BusinessUnitRepository>().CtorDependency<IDatabaseFactory>().Is<DatabaseFactory>();
```

When I run the program SM throws a 302 error when trying to create an instance of `BusinessUnitRepository`.

```
StructureMap.StructureMapException: StructureMap Exception Code:  302
There is no argument of type Repository.LinqToSql.IDatabaseFactory for concrete type Repository.LinqToSql.BusinessUnitRepository
```

**FYI:**

- If I do reference StructureMap in the Repository.LinqToSql.BusinessUnitRepository assembly and use the [DefaultConstructor] attribute on my IDatabaseFactory constructor everything works perfectly.
- Also I have confirmed that StructureMap does contain a configured 'Repository.LinqToSql.DatabaseFactory'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution but the 'magic' has a stink:

```
ForRequestedType<Repository.IBusinessUnitRepository>()
            .CacheBy( InstanceScope.PerRequest )
            .TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType<BusinessUnitRepository>()
            .CtorDependency<IDatabaseFactory>("factory").IsTheDefault();

SelectConstructor<BusinessUnitRepository>( () => new BusinessUnitRepository((IDatabaseFactory)null ) );
```

I still think there is a better answer.  Since I have quite a few Repository interfaces and concrete implementation it seems like a lot of work to define the `SelectConstructor` for each type.  I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Which class implements IBusinessUnitRepository?
If you have a suggestion for how you think it should work, please post to the StructureMap mailing list. http://groups.google.com/group/structuremap-users

Comment: Joshua, the BusinessUnitRepository implements IBusinessUnitRepository.